# Is it possible to filter out multiple words from a text into a new column in R

Tags: r

I would like to filter out food related words from a text spanning multiple rows. I have tried using the following code below, but it is able to only filter out one word at a time. Would it be possible to filter out multiple words at the same time in a new column called df$Food?

`df$Food <- ifelse(grepl("apple", df$text), "Apple", ifelse(grepl("banana", df$text), "Banana",  ifelse(grepl("pear", df$text), "Pear","no")))`

The df is listed below

```
ID  text
1   Mary ate apples
2   She liked the bananas and apples
3   but not as much as the pear
4   although bananas and pears go well together
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` in `sapply` and use `which` for getting the food.

```
x <- c("Apple", "Banana", "Pear")
y <- sapply(x, grepl, df$text, ignore.case = TRUE)
df$Food <- apply(y, 1, function(i) paste(x[which(i)], collapse=", "))
df
#  ID                                        text          Food
#1  1                             Mary ate apples         Apple
#2  2            She liked the bananas and apples Apple, Banana
#3  3                 but not as much as the pear          Pear
#4  4 although bananas and pears go well together  Banana, Pear
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:4, text=c("Mary ate apples","She liked the bananas and apples"
 ,"but not as much as the pear","although bananas and pears go well together"))
```

Comment: The second line of the ouput does not contain bananas, as well as the 4th which does not have Pear.

Comment: Hi GKi,  thank you for your responds. I think I have been a bit unclear. Although the code you suggested fulfils the first requirement, I would like to have the filter so that it also adds all the foods mentioned in lines where multiple foods are mentioned. So result for df$Food with ID 2 should ideally be "Banana" ,"Apple".

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this solution!

Comment: @TimBeijer O, I have thought you want the same result like your code is producing. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Food = stringr::str_extract_all(df$text,
                                         "(apple)|(banana)|(pear)")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(Food))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID text                                        Food  
  <dbl> <chr>                                       <chr> 
1     1 Mary ate apples                             apple 
2     2 She liked the bananas and apples            banana
3     2 She liked the bananas and apples            apple 
4     3 but not as much as the pear                 pear  
5     4 although bananas and pears go well together banana
6     4 although bananas and pears go well together pear
```

Returning:

Or you could skip the `unnest()` part to leave vectors of fruit strings in the fruit column.

```
# Data used:
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), text = c("Mary ate apples", "She liked the bananas and apples", "but not as much as the pear", "although bananas and pears go well together")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr::str_extract_all` to extract all the fruits in `text` column and collapse them in one comma separated string.

```
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "pear")

df$fruits <- sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$text, 
                    sprintf('(%s)', paste0(fruits, collapse = '|'))), toString)

df

#  ID                                        text        fruits
#1  1                             Mary ate apples         apple
#2  2            She liked the bananas and apples banana, apple
#3  3                 but not as much as the pear          pear
#4  4 although bananas and pears go well together  banana, pear
```